How can I determine the join conditions using access history and query history from snowflake?
Is it possible to determine the join conditions using the access history and query history objects out of Snowflake?
We are already using the access and query history views in order to get summary information about which tables and views are being accessed, but I would like to also be able to show which tables are being joined together and the fields that are being used as keys.
The only way I can figure out how to do this so far is to use regex to try and extract the table/view and field values using something like
join|JOIN|Join|JOin|JOIn|jOIN [A-z0-9\. \n[:space:]]*on|ON|On|oN ([A-z0-9]*).([A-z0-9 ]*)=([A-z0-9 ]*).([A-z0-9]*)

This approach has two limitations.

It only returns the table reference name, not the actual full table namespace, which isn't ideal
It misses more joins than it finds because of the inconsistency with which people are writing SQL.  I was hoping it was possible to get this join information out of the access_history table using the base_objects_accessed field, but it isn't obvious to me how to do this and I haven't found any documentation explaining it.

I suspect I'm going to have to write something in python to use more sophisticated text extraction than I can get out of regex_substr.
Does anyone have any thoughts or suggestions?

What you are looking for is the actual EXPLAIN output for all queries that have been executed.  Unfortunately, that isn't available in Snowflake (you should open a request for this with Support!).  That said, you could run through query_history and execute an EXPLAIN for the SQL Text of every query and store it somewhere to evaluate.  The EXPLAIN statement doesn't require a warehouse, so it only uses services layer of Snowflake.  EXPLAIN contains the join information that you are looking for!
